# position of schema in article

Tags: tikz-pgf

when I remove the standalone class and put the figure in the document, I have just a part of the schema

[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[edges]{forest}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
 \begin{forest}
  for tree={draw,edge={-latex},parent anchor=south,align=center,
  }
  [Ontological models and languages\\ 
    for mathematical knowledge management\\ 
    on the Semantic Web 
    [Terminological Ressources\\ and Symbolic Notation\\ for Mathematical domain
    [Terminological Ressources
 [Vocabularies
[The Online Encyclopedia\\ of Integer Sequences]
 ]
  [pft1nnnnnnnn\\nnnnnnnnnnnnnnn12
[pftnnnnnnnnnn\\
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn1121]
[pft1122]
 ]  
   ]
    [pftgggggggggg12
      [pfggggggggt121
  [pfggggggggggt1211]
  ]
   [pftggggggg122
  [pfggggggggt1221]
   ]  
  [pftggggggggg123
  [pfggggggggggt1231]
 ]  
 ]
]
[pfgggggggt2
[pftgggggggggg21
 [pftnnnnnnnnn\\
 nnnnnnnnnnnnnnn211]
 [pfnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnt212]  
     ]
       [pfjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjt22]
    ]
     ]
   \end{forest}
    \centering
  \caption{\textbf{The multilevel of the abstraction.}\label{fig:tree}}
   \end{figure}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! As I noted to your previous question, in such long sequences of letters, which `babel` don't know how to hyphenate them, you need to do this manually. You need to make your nodes narrower. Also default text width of the `article` is relative small, so you are in trouble with your tree diagram. A possible solution is put your `forest` image onto landscape oriented page (for example by using `sidewaystable` from the `rotating` package).

Comment: Are text in your nodes really consist from such long sequences of letters or it is composed from many shorter words? In later case, you can prescribe nodes widths.

Comment: can I oriented my image and how or displayed them in paysage

Comment: See my answer below. Note: only rotating of figure will not solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

(to long for the comment)

Your problem is very weak related to LateX. The main problem is formatting of nodes' contents. From LaTeX side you can do only two things:

- Rotate figure to landscape orientation. For example with use of the `rotating` package:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{rotating}
  \usepackage[edges]{forest}

  \begin{document}
      \begin{sidewaysfigure}
  ....
      \end{sidewaysfigure}
  \end{document}
  ```

  Also with this solution your table will not fit on a page.
- Reduce font size so  that figure will fit to text width or at least to text hight (if you will rotate figure). However doing this,  you will quickly run into the illegibility of the text in figure.

So only promising solution is combination of the following:

- Slightly reduce font size, but not more than to `\footnotesize`.
- Reformat your nodes contents, that nodes become narrower. In this we can help you since the real text is unknown to us.
- Eventually rotate figure if needed.

**Addendum:**
an example of your tree when contents of nodes are sequences of (shorter) words, for font size is selected `\footnotesize` and nodes widths are determined by `text width=...`  differently for lower three levels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{forest}
for tree={draw,
    edge={-latex},
    parent anchor=south,
    child  anchor=north,
    font=\footnotesize,
    text centered,
    text width=31mm,
    where level=2{text width=21mm}{},
    where level=3{text width=17mm}{},
    where level=4{text width=13mm}{},
    tier/.option=level,
    l sep=9mm,
    s sep=1mm,
}
[Ontological models and languages for mathematical knowledge management on the Semantic Web
 [Terminological Ressources and Symbolic Notation for Mathematical domain
  [Terminological Ressources
   [Vocabularies
    [The Online Encyclopedia of Integer]
   ]
   [pft1 nnn nnnnn nnnnnn nnn nnnn nn12
    [pft1122]
   ]
  ]
  [pft gg ggggg ggg 12
   [pfggg gggggt121
    [pfgg ggggg gggt 1211]
   ]
   [pft ggg gggg 122
    [pf ggg ggggg t1221]
   ]
   [pft ggggg gggg 123
    [pfg gggg gg gggt 1231]
   ]
  ]
 ]
 [pfgggggggt2
  [pftgggg gg gggg 21
   [pft nnn nnnnnn nnnnnnn nn nnnnnn 211]
   [pfn nn nnnnnn nnnnn nn nnnnnt 212]
  ]
  [pfjj jjj jjjjjj jjjjjj t22]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\centering
\caption{\textbf{The multilevel of the abstraction.}
\label{fig:tree}}
    \end{figure}
```

This enables to fit figure on page with 25mm wide borders:

[image]

(the red lines indicate the boundaries of the text area)